# Getting Beautiful to run through a list after finishing pagination

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I am learning both python and web-scraping, so please forgive me if this is something extremely basic.

I found a script and modified it to scrape yell.com

Now, I understand pagination. And am able to scrape the entire set of one city using code similar to the one below.

```
for x in range(1,9):
    print(f'Scraping page {x}')
    content = extract(f'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=134234234&keywords=dentists&location=birmingham&pageNum={x}')
    transform(content)
    time.sleep(5)

load()
print('Saved to CSV')
```

Now, I have a list of cities that I'd like to scrape.

So for instance, the `location=birmingham` parameter above would change `location=portsmouth`

The solution I have come up with is to define the entire city list in an array (it could be huge) and then call them.

However, I want the scrape to run through the entire range defined above and then move on to a different city, with the range reset. And I can't figure that bit out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to include a second for loop to go through your long list of cities. Then `city` can be included into your URL. For example:

```
cities = ['birmingham', 'portsmouth', 'london']  # long list of cities

for city in cities:
    print(f'City - {city}')
    
    for x in range(1, 9):
        print(f'Scraping page {x}')
        content = extract(f'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=134234234&keywords=dentists&location={city}&pageNum={x}')
        transform(content)
        time.sleep(5)

load()
print('Saved to CSV')
```